# When writing to a file, how do I correctly resolve access to path is denied?

Tags: vb.net, file, streamwriter

Here is my code:

```
Dim htmlFile = "\\folder\test.htm"
If File.Exists(htmlFile) Then
    File.Delete(htmlFile)
End If
Using strWriter As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(htmlFile, False)
    strWriter.Write("content")
End Using
```

It works most of the time but occasionally I'll get an exception of "Access to the path '\folder\test.htm' is denied." The exception occurs on this line:

```
Using strWriter As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fileName, False)
```

How can I ensure that it always creates a new file and never causes an exception?

Comment: If it works most of time, the problem is NOT related to the code, but other thing is occurring at the same time. Put a TRY-CATCH and try to see exactly which the type of exception you are getting there. And, the problem may be related to the DELETE, not the WRITE itself...

Comment: It is inside of a try-catch. I edited my question. The exception occurs on the Using line.

Comment: @DavidBS perhaps the delete didn't finish? And then when it tries to write to it, it errors out.

Comment: In WIndows 8 some folders are "app-protected", forcing us to use COMMON folders (like <User>\AppData\Local). Sometimes, using a FULL PATH can cause also the problem.  The question is: the error occurs always in the same folder or in different folders? Is it possible to the file be opened in another app or even in your app?

Comment: Yeah it's on a shared folder. The app resides on two servers. Those two servers access that shared folder. Perhaps I need to think of a different solution then... maybe appending a date stamp to the file name.

Comment: You gave me probably the solution: both app may be writing the same file or, while one try to delete the file, the other is writing it! And no, timestamp won´t correct it since both servers may write at the same time. Try to add a prefix like "srv1.page.html" or "srv2.page.html" or, create a routine to LOOP while in error to accessing the SAME FILE, waiting some seconds to retry.

Comment: See below a kind of answer....

Answer (score -1):

This routine waits some time in case of error betweens 2 servers writing the same file:

```
Retry_IT:

try
      Dim htmlFile = "\\folder\test.htm"
      If File.Exists(htmlFile) Then
         File.Delete(htmlFile)
      End If
      Using strWriter As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(htmlFile, False)
         strWriter.Write("content")
      End Using
Catch Exception
      Thread.sleep(2000)   '2 seconds
      Goto Retry_It
End Try
```

Comment: Should be very interesting before VOTE DOWN: 1) see the context of that answer in relation to the comments above; or  2) explain why exactly it couldn´t be utilized AND suggest a better approach related to the same comments above.  It should be more pro-active.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer. I think my issue probably could be solved by simply using a database instead of writing the file to disk. It doesn't make sense the way the previous programmer did this - they are creating a new HTML file for the client to download. The same can be done with a simply aspx page that gets the contents from the DB.

Comment: I didn´t expecte you had done it... But someone did.  You can utilize a database for sure, or even a TEXT FILE to act like a database. But, using a database, you must be sure the environment has a database engine or provide one, correctly adapted and planned to the amount of data,